# The congruence $ax \equiv 1 \mod 1$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Consider this statement:

$ax \equiv 1 \pmod n\,$ has a solution iff $\gcd(a,n) = 1$.

Let $a = 1, n = 1$. Then $\gcd(1,1) = 1$ but no solution exists.

Comment: What's $n$ in this stuff?

Comment: In (mod 1) every number is 0

Comment: This question is badly written. I would assume it should be something like that "For any $a,n$ there exists $x$ such that $ax\equiv 1 \text{ mod } n$ if and only if $\gcd(a,n)=1$."

Comment: From https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse: "The previous result says that a solution exists if and only if gcd(a, m) = 1, that is, a and m must be relatively prime (i.e. coprime)."

Comment: When $a=1,n=1$, then _any_ integer $x$ solves $x\equiv 1\pmod 1$. This is because, modulo $1$, all integers are equivalent.

Comment: By definition $\,a\equiv b\pmod{\! 1}\iff 1\mid a−b.\,$ Since $1$ divides every integer that is always true, so modulo $1$ every integer is congruent to $\,0,\,$ i.e. the integers mod $1=\Bbb Z/1 =0\,$ is the zero ring with $1$ element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the fact that, for instance, $6\equiv 4\pmod 2$ (i.e. modulo is not an *operation* in this context). Then apply that thinking to modulo $1$ and see that your problem isn't a problem: $ax\equiv 1\pmod 1$ comes automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your problem: $x=1$ is a valid solution: $1=1 \pmod{1}$..?
Even $x=2$ is one, etc. as $1 \equiv 2 \pmod{1}$ too.